# ASP.net link button event skipped?

Tags: c#, asp.net

im trying to create a `gridview` with some column and in one column its suppose to be a link button every time i try to click it the event skips and it goes right to the page instead? It worked just a sec ago but now it wont.

code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ärendenummer">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="linkBtn" 
Text='<%# Eval("ID")%>' OnClick="sendID_Click" 
PostBackUrl="~/coordinator/CrimeCoordinator.aspx" runat="server"/>
                        </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: What's in your sendID_Click event handler? Please share that code, too.

Comment: please provide us the code for "sendID_Click"

Answer (score 0):

use `Rowcommand` in Gridview

**Aspx Code:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"   EmptyDataText="No Records Found !">
 <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ärendenummer">
           <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="linkBtn" CommandName="Demo" 
Text='<%# Eval("ID")%>'  
PostBackUrl="~/coordinator/CrimeCoordinator.aspx" runat="server"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField> 
 </Columns>
```

**C# Code**

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Demo")
        {

        }

    }
```